# Delphi 11.3 in Windows 11 connected Mac (MacOS Ventura 13.3.1) over Wifi running PAServer 22 Connection fails?

Tags: delphi

I have Delphi 11.3 in Windows 11 connected Mac (MacOS Ventura 13.3.1) over Wifi running PAServer 22
Pressing the "Test Connection" button in "Connection Profile Manager" always gives me "Remote error: Unknow LifeCycle: Sessio" message.
I have searched forums and all the items of the pop-up error solutions page that displays after failure attempts, but I cannot find solution...

error :    "Remote error: Unknow LifeCycle: Sessio"

Thank you.

I was hoping someone here might have suggestions or point me in the right direction for looking for solution.

Comment: The correct link for PAServer for macOS is: https://altd.embarcadero.com/releases/studio/22.0/113/PAServer22.0.pkg. Going by your description, you're attempting to connect to a **Windows** machine running PAServer, using a macOS profile

Comment: Sorry, i got the wrong link , 

Currently I am using the version 13.3.12.7  , 

I go the following error "Remote error: Unknow LifeCycle: Sessio"

Comment: Edit your question. Don't link pictures that contain texts - post the texts instead. In error dialog windows you can press Ctrl+C to copy all the text into the clipboard. Take the [tour].

Comment: @HoanganhPhạm Please read my comment again - you are trying to connect to PAServer on Windows, but you are using a macOS profile. You need to install PAServer on the Mac and connect to that

Comment: @Dave Nottage
 I am trying to connect to PAServer on MACOS , not Windows , i installed PAServer22.0.pkg , I start PAServer on the Mac , blank password , type i to get the ip , type P to get the Port , When Pressing the "Test Connection" button in "Connection Profile Manager" , i get error "Remote error: Unknow LifeCycle: Sessio" message

Comment: OK.. not sure what could be causing that